# ADO.NET model is not updating stored procedure changes

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ado.net, ado.net-entity-data-model

I have added ADO.NET entity framework model in my project. When I do changes in **stored procedure** it is not reflecting that change in **ADO.NET** entity model. I tried to remove old stored procedure from model and update model once again but ADO.NET model is not updating that changes. Can someone please help me to solve this ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide the code you are using?

Comment: I have added it by Clicking New Items -> ADO.NET Entity Data Model. And when I update it I just right click on it and click **Update Model From Database**.

Comment: what version of VS/entities are you using?

Comment: @AjayPunekar I've had problems like that before.  Try going into the Model visualizer, using `Ctrl+A` to select everything, and delete it all.  Then try `Update Model From Database` again

Comment: vs 2012 and 4.5 framework

Comment: @Jonesy I will try this and let you know. Visualizer means the diagram which show database and it's relationship connections

Comment: @AjayPunekar Yeah, the diagram

Comment: This may sound stupid, but I used to have this problem with vs2010 - closing and re- opening vs always did the trick...

Answer (score 0):

This is a functional limitation in the designer. Take a look at [this work](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/2203) item on codeplex - it contains a work around for this.